# why are drawables colored in black on some mobile phones?

Tags: android, drawable

In my application I have got a few drawables and I give the user the possibilty to change the backgroundcolor with sharedpreferences. The problem is, that on some mobile phones the drawables are colored in black even if no sharedpreferences are set. The problem occures on older mobile phones API Level < 19.

I tried it also with `drawable.setColorFilter(...)`:

```
        Resources resForColorFilter = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        Drawable drawableForColorFilter = resForColorFilter.getDrawable(R.drawable.soundshape);

        if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase("backgroundcolorString")){
            Log.d("in backgroundcolorString", "in backgroundcolorString");
            drawableForColorFilter.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        }


        try {
            if(!(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase(textFarbePref))){
                drawableForColorFilter.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(backgroundcolorPref), PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

            // wenn die Hintergrundfarbe gleich der Textfarbe ist
            } else if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase(textFarbePref)) {

                // wenn der Hintergrund schwarz gefärbt ist
                if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase("#000000")){
                    textFarbePref = "#FFFFFF";
                } else if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase("#ffffff")){
                    textFarbePref = "#000000";
                } else {
                    textFarbePref = "#000000";
                }

            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException){
            drawableForColorFilter.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        }

        Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.soundshape);
        // das geladene Design auf der TextView anwenden, damit ein abgerunter Rahmen erscheint
        soundUmrandung.setBackground(drawable);         
        if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase("backgroundcolorString")){
            Log.d("in backgroundcolorString", "in backgroundcolorString");
            drawableForColorFilter.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        }


        try {
            if(!(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase(textFarbePref))){
                drawableForColorFilter.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(backgroundcolorPref), PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

            // wenn die Hintergrundfarbe gleich der Textfarbe ist
            } else if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase(textFarbePref)) {

                // wenn der Hintergrund schwarz gefärbt ist
                if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase("#000000")){
                    textFarbePref = "#FFFFFF";
                } else if(backgroundcolorPref.equalsIgnoreCase("#ffffff")){
                    textFarbePref = "#000000";
                } else {
                    textFarbePref = "#000000";
                }

            }
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException){
            drawableForColorFilter.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        }

        Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.soundshape);
        // das geladene Design auf der TextView anwenden, damit ein abgerunter Rahmen erscheint
        soundUmrandung.setBackground(drawable);
```

Why are drawables on some mobile phones colored in black?

Ok, well this seems to be a bug of API Level 16. I solved the problem by using transparency with `drawable.setAlpha(0)`.

Just a little problem remains: the corners of the buttons, and which I specified in xml aren't visible anymore.